How to change file order in vscode explorer?
Now my explorer like this:order of my vscode explore now
I want to change their order to :
1.typ
2.pdf
3.png
The setting of vscode explore order only have option like : mixed,filesFirst,type,modified,etc.
Is there have any way i can Customize their order?

It looks like you have "type" selected for "Explorer: Sort Order". Did you try the option "default"?

You can configure how files and folders are sorted in the File Explorer using the explorer.sortOrder setting. As you mentioned, there are four options to choose from:

filesFirst: Sort files before folders.
mixed: Sort files and folders together without separation.
modified: Sort by the last modified time.
type: Sort by file type.

Unfortunately, adding or changing options beyond these is not possible.
